# Spring Tool Suite failing to start with error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I was using Spring tool suite, I just upgraded it to latest version `spring-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.3.2-linux-gtk-x86_64` and now I am not able to start it. It gives below error:

```
VM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/vishal/install/sts/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/vishal/install/sts/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS
-name STS
--launcher.library /home/vishal/install/sts/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212/eclipse_1508.so
-startup /home/vishal/install/sts/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 98006
-product org.springsource.sts.ide
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/vishal/install/sts/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

I have ubuntu 12.04 and this Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

This is STS.ini

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: looks like it searching for java version 1.6. Although I am not familiar with spring suite but found "-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m" in your logs above

Comment: yeah I observer that, but it was working fine before, why would upgrading to latest version ask for old java version ?

Comment: Can you post your STS.ini file?

Comment: posted,why it looks for javaVersion1.6 ? It used to work with 1.7 before upgrading

Comment: What version did you have before upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

The above error cause by STS version.

At this site: http://spring.io/tools/sts/all , Download STS version what support **32 bit (x86)** or **64 bit (x64)** computer.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not a java developer but had to look into java code.I faced the same issue stated above and fixed it in different way. located STS.ini, opened it and changed the version from 1.6 to 1.7. bingo... its started working..

Comment: This is more like a comment rather an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem after another software updated 1.8 32 bit client VM, where I am running on 64 bit Windows 7. This issue was resolved after I installed JDK 1.8 64 bit Server VM.

Answer (score 0):

The .ini file you posted points to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java` but the error log shows it's actually using `/usr/bin/java`. That suggests you're not using the .ini you think you are. Double check you're launching from the correct directory/executable.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the case here, but usually this kind of error means the JVM is 32 bit where it needs to be 64 bit or vice versa. Double check that the JVM you are using matches your downloaded STS with respect to 32/64 bit.

Also the answer from E-Riz makes sense. Check exactly what '/usr/bin/java' actually points to (it is probably a symlink). Try the following commands

```
/usr/bin/java -version
```

Also track down the symlink

```
ls -la /usr/bin/java
```

This will tell you where it points (probably /etc/alternatives/java, which is another symlink. Repeat until you get to the end of the symlink chain. If this doesn't lead to where you think it should (i.e. /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java) then E-riz is right and you are probably not running the STS.ini that you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve this error in so many ways, but nothing worked for me. At last I uninstalled all my java installations from Control Panel, and reinstalled Java 1.8 and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

This error with STS is pretty common when you start for the first time. Here is what I found on YouTube, will help eliminate the error: https://youtu.be/cMClVM6rzuc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to open Sprint STS on my Windows machine  (64 bits).

The problem was, in fact, that the STS download page, by default, downloads the Windows 32 bits version and it was not working because of that on my 64 bits Windows.

I just went to the STS download page again and download the right version (64 bits) and it solved my issue.

Best regards!